# PHP 'stdClass not an object'

Tags: php, class, object, stdclass

Fetching rows **as objects** from a MySQL database via **mysqli::fetch_object** (all **PHP5**), they look like this on **var_dump**:

```
class stdClass#5 (5) {
  public $id =>
  string(2) "23"
  public $started =>
  NULL
  public $finished =>
  NULL
  public $mode =>
  string(3) "XML"
  public $mail =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Now on doing this:

```
    public function __construct($export) {
        var_dump($export);
        if (!($export instanceof stdClass)) {
//throw new exception ...
}
```

or this

```
public function __construct(stdClass $export) {
        var_dump($export);
//...
```

or even with `is_object($export)`  - this fails

I actually get an Exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'
with message '$export is not an object'
```

or

```
Argument 1 passed to ConverterXML::__construct()
must be an instance of stdClass, none given
```

1. **why**

   - or even better -
2. **How** do I get to check weather $export is an anonymouse class from mysqli fetch_object?

Comment: Hmm... http://3v4l.org/MJtWp? You sure you're actually passing something/the right thing? "***None*** given" seems to say otherwise.

Comment: see the [fetch-object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) manual you can set class_name but If not specified, a `stdClass` object is returned.

Comment: the var_dump shows that $export contains more then 'None'. It actually contains an stdClass.

Comment: Can you post your entire code? It seems you're getting an array of objects, but it's difficult to tell without seeing *how* exactly you fetch data.

Comment: If you are using namespace then you must use `\stdClass` not `stdClass`. Maybe here lies your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be no problems, if you are doing it correctly like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    var_dump( $obj );
    var_dump( $obj instanceof stdClass );
    var_dump( is_object( $obj ) );
}
```

or, if you want instance of different object than stdClass:

```
class Employee {
    public function __construct( $id ) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
$i = 0;
while ( $obj = $result->fetch_object( "Employee", array( $i ) ) ) {
    var_dump( $obj );
    $i++;
}
```